# Django: Passing data to views from pre_save

Tags: python, django

I have the following issue: I want to pass data from my model pre_save function to my views.py

The reason is that in my pre_save function, there is a unique order_id generated. This unique order id must also be saved in a session id (request.session['order_id'] = unique_order_id). Models don't accept a request, so I am trying to save it in my views.py, but how do I get the generated unique order id there?

Appreciate your help!

views.py

```
def another_view(request):

    if request.POST:
        # Generate unique order_id
        x = Order().save()
        request.session['order_id'] = x
        # This is how I hoped it to solve, but x is not passing any data, even when adding a return variable in pre_save
```

models.py

```
# Imports (removed)
# Create your models here.
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id    = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order_id)

def order_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.order_id = unique_id_generator(instance)
    # Here the unique order id is generated. Additionally I want to save this id as a session.



pre_save.connect(order_pre_save_receiver, sender=Order)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `x = Order().save()` you are creating an order object updating it and not preserving it

`save()` method does not returns any model object instead updates the object it is called with

So what you have to do is

```
x = Order()
x.save() # at this point pre_save is called and unique id is updated
x.order_id # will be your updated order id
```

Comment: or just `x = Order.objects.create(...)` which does both `x = Order(); x.save()` in a single operation.